# How should we handle random number generation in languages without it built in?

Tags: discussion, random

A number of programming languages have no built-in way to generate random numbers. How are we able to include these languages in a challenge requiring random output?

Comment: Could you provide examples of such languages please?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers BF

Comment: I'd wager that most esolangs don't support randomness, and most of those that do are ones with random behavior in core features of the language. The largest class of exceptions would probably be the golflangs, but even within the golflangs there's not perfect support for randomness: Husk is purely functional, and omits any random builtins on principle.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15025/what-are-the-standard-requirements-for-answering-a-random-challenge

Comment: [Random Brainfuck](https://tio.run/##K0rMS8nP1U0qSszMSytNzv4PBAA)

Comment: Possible dupe of https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17128/45941

Answer (score 6):

## We don't

The unfortunate fact is that not every language can answer every challenge. I can't answer most, if not all, [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system) challenges using [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), as it doesn't have the capacity to read files. And that's fine. If a language is unable to produce a random number in a valid way [according to our rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15026/66833), then it cannot compete in a [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) challenge.

Comment: Given that no answer's have been posted yet, I thought turning my comment into a full answer would be good